# How to pivot data frame

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to pivot (or unstack?) a data frame based on an ID field from something like this:

```
ID  Col1    Col2
1   a   aa
2   b   bb
3   c   cc
3   d   dd
```

To this:

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col1    Col2
1   a   aa      
2   b   bb      
3   c   cc           d      dd
```

So i'm trying:

```
df2 = df.pivot(None, 'ID')
```

Which gives me error:

> builtins.IndexError: index 1796516957 is out of bounds for axis 0 with
>   size 1796298784

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `MultiIndex` columns:

```
a = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['ID', a]).unstack(fill_value='').sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
```

Alternative with `apply`:

```
c = ['Col1','Col2']
df = (df.groupby('ID')[c]
       .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, columns=c))
       .unstack(fill_value='')
       .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
```

```
print (df)
   Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2
      0    0    1    1
ID                    
1     a   aa          
2     b   bb          
3     c   cc    d   dd
```

---

For duplicates column names use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
print (df)

   Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2
ID                    
1     a   aa          
2     b   bb          
3     c   cc    d   dd
```

For unique columns names use `join`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)

   Col1_0 Col2_0 Col1_1 Col2_1
ID                            
1       a     aa              
2       b     bb              
3       c     cc      d     dd
```